# SciPy ImportError on Python 2.6 Anaconda

Tags: python, scipy, python-2.6, anaconda

I developed a Python package using Python 2.7 and 3.4, and now I'm trying to test it for 2.6 compatibility. So in Anaconda, I made a new conda environment for Python 2.6:

```
conda create -n python2.6 python=2.6.9 numpy scipy
```

But now, when I try to import some stuff from scipy:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.9 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (unknown, Jan 10 2014, 13:33:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy.sparse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jsleinon/anaconda/envs/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 212, in <module>
from .csr import *
  File "/Users/jsleinon/anaconda/envs/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 13, in <module>
from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jsleinon/anaconda/envs/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZNSaIcEC1Ev
  Referenced from: /Users/jsleinon/anaconda/envs/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Does anybody know a fix or a workaround? I'm using Mac OS X 10.9. The import works fine on 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: I can reproduce that issue. You may need help from the devs here. AFAIK, asmeurer  frequently looks through `anaconda` questions here on SO. Putting a ticket on github is another option.

Comment: I've seen this issue reported before https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/89. I don't know if a solution was ever found, though.

Comment: It looks like a workaround is to use scipy=0.14 (or use a newer version of Python, as you noted).